# htaccess to redirect all files to index.php apart from a specific subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess

I have a site in which all requests should go to index.php, apart from those in a specific subdirectory, which should go to subdirectory/index.php.

I would like the directory path to be translated to a query string for use in the subdirectory index page.

I really have very little idea about htaccess files and I'm sure this question has been answered a hundred times, but I can't work out what to search for to get an answer.

So - this is what I would like to happen under these conditions...

```
RULE 1
www.example.com/anything_or_nothing <goes to> /index.php
www.example.com/anything/anything_else <goes to> /index.php
RULE 2
www.example.com/subdirectory/ <goes to> /subdirectory/index.php
RULE 3
www.example.com/subdirectory/some_other_directory/ <goes to> /subdirectory/index.php?a=some_other_directory
```

This is what I have currently.  It doesn't work - At least, RULE 1 does work, RULE 2 works (though I think this is only because the physical /subdirectory exists and the index.php is served as a default.) **RULE 3 doesn't work.**

```
Options All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/?timeline/
#RULE 1
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
#RULE 2
RewriteRule ^/sub.*$ /sub/index.php
#RULE 3
RewriteRule ^/sub/([^/\.]+)/?$ /sub/index.php?a=$1 [L,NC]
```

I have been unable to get a .htaccess file working in the subdirectory, so I'd like the rules all to be in the root .htaccess file.

I have cobbled this .htaccess together from other sites, so I do apologise for my level of ignorance, but I'm just not sure where to go...

Thank you in advance.

ADDITIONAL INFO>>>>>>>>

Other things I have tried.

This

```
RewriteRule ^/sub/([^/\.]+)/?$ /sub/index.php?a=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/sub.*$ /sub/index.php
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

Stops all rules from working.

This:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
RewriteRule ^/sub/([^/\.]+)/?$ /sub/index.php?a=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^/sub.*$ /sub/index.php
```

Seems to behave as the original example.

Comment: Did you try to change the order of the RewriteRules?
For example reverse it.

Comment: Thanks for responding - I have tried this - Edits in above post.

Answer (score 0):

As you answered yourself the second rule is unecessary.

```
# Don't rewrite if file already exists to prevent rewriting images, scripts etc
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .* - [L]

# Rewrite sub/anything to sub/index.php?a=anything
RewriteRule ^sub/([^/]+)$ sub/index.php?a=$1 [L,NC]

# Fallback all unknown requests to index.php
RewriteRule .* index.php [L,NC]
```

A note of warning: this approach will completely hide all natural 404 errors as you're rewriting non-existing files to **index.php**.